# Facebook Ads click tracking through url parameters/tags is it possible?

Tags: facebook, advertising, tracking, click-tracking

Is there something like ValueTrack for AdWords but for Facebook ads?

And I'm not talking about Google Analytics UTM tags.

Looking through documentation, brought me to some API documentation that is close to the topic but it's not the same. For example something like that:
`http://example.com?var1={val1}&var2={val2}`
And the parameters like ad group or some demographic data is being automatically in curly braces, instead of val1, val2 and etc.

Conversion pixel tracking is not the option since I don't own the domain, I will point my ads to.